# How to make use of hovering on a div that is below another div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I try to make a menu on the side of my website which rolls out when hovered on it. First I had its width expand but the text would look weird so I figured I would use CSS animation to change the position of the div such that it would move to the right. The problem I get is that those menu divs  overlay the 'main' div. The only way to get these divs under the main div is to use `z-index: -1` but then `:hover` doesn't work anymore. I have tried `pointer-events: none;` but that also doens't seem to work.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <img id="mainpic" src="pokebalicon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="sidediv" id="first">
        <p>Homepage</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpage">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container {
    width: 820px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainpage {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #D5D4D4;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.sidediv{
    position: absolute;
    left: 721px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

`.sidediv:hover` starts an animation which changes `left` such that it looks like it's being pulled out. But sadly nothing happens when hovering over a sidediv. Any idea how to solve this?

The hovering looks like this:

```
.sidediv:hover{
    -webkit-animation: example 0.5s forwards;
    animation: example 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    100% {left: 841px;}
}
@keyframes example {
    100% {left: 841px;}
}
```

Comment: Can you post an updated code where actually you are using `:hover` and point to the div where you want to take that action

Comment: It just calls an animation which changes the `left` attribute like I said. It works if I don't set the sidediv's z-index to -1, but after that the hover function is just gone.

Comment: Can you please share a working fiddle it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
#container {
  width: 820px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainpage {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D4D4;
}

.sidediv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 721px;
  top: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.7s
}

#container #mainpage:hover + .sidediv {
  z-index: 1;
  background: pink;
  left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <img id="mainpic" src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="mainpage">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="sidediv" id="first">
    <p>Homepage</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. `z-index` feels weird to me as well. I though when a div has a higher z-index than another div, it would be placed on top of the other. But I can only get the sidediv below the other div when using the value -1. It doesn't seem to work with any other value so maybe that is a part of the problem.